# Can I save wet biscuits?

Tags: food-safety, biscuits

In the rainy season biscuits and other dry goods become wet under their packing. Can they be recovered?

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance, Favour returned: Question upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put them in the oven at 100 °C (212 °F, the boiling point of water) and all the humidity will dry out naturally.

The time depends on the size and amount of water in the biscuits:

- smaller and damp: 5 minutes
- large and very wet: up to 20 minutes.

Comment: but if oven is not available so what we should do in this case.any other method or technique for drying biscuits .

Comment: @SherniMalik That would be [a new question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)  Please refer to the link of this question to provide context.